# How to record timestamp of modification of OneToOneField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im basically asking, what is the simplest way of updating modified_time in my ExtendedProfile model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  

class ExtendedProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

if the user model is edited, because this seems only to work, if I edit the ExtendedProfile fields.

Comment: Note that using a Profile model with a OneToOne to User is no longer recommended: you should define a custom user model which extends AbstractUser and point the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to write a `post_save` signal handler (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) for User model I believe.

Alternatively, you can specify custom user model and extend it from AbstractUser so you don't have to think about OneToOne relations. Assuming you are using latest version of django. Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model